how infer method params with self object (literal)
How can I ensure that when I comment out line 37 with components: [1, 2], the argument c in available: (c) => { is not never but get type number?
The main issue is that if I comment out this line, all the others entries, even if they have different components:[...], become (c:never)=>{}.
I would also like the argument c in method to fallback to type number rather than never if the components property is not provided.
enum AAA {
    a1 = 'a1', a2 = 'a2', a3 = 'a3',
}
enum BBB {
    b1 = 'b1', b2 = 'b2', b3 = 'b3',
}


type TestData<T extends number = number> = {
    components?: T[];
    avaible: (c: T) => void; 
}

// Adjust the RR type to allow partial records for both AAA and BBB
type RR = Partial<Record<AAA, Partial<Record<BBB, number>>>>;


type Param<T extends RR> = {
    [KA in keyof T & AAA]?: {
        [KB in keyof T[KA] & BBB]?: TestData<Extract<T[KA][KB], number>>
    }
}

class Test<T extends RR> {
    constructor(
        public readonly data: Param<T>
    ) { }
}


// this is a db with literal entries
// i want pass to (c) type from .components or if not defined, juste use number
new Test(
    {
        [AAA.a1]: {
            [BBB.b1]: {
                components: [1, 2], // if i remove this, c should number and not never !?
                avaible: (c) => {
                    //    ^?
                }
            },
        },
        [AAA.a2]: {
            [BBB.b2]: {
                components: [5],
                avaible: (c) => {
                   //    ^?
                }
            },
              [BBB.b1]: {
                components: [8],
                avaible: (c) => {
                   //    ^?
                }
            },
        },
    }
);


playground

hi @jcalz, this is for building a commands database like but literal instead use a software i use a IDE. I'm describe commands as data entries, and I can include a method that contains an instance auto-inheriting the usage conditions from the context.
the gameobject is représente as number in the example
img: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1008286585034375189/1279520857500422256/image.png?ex=66d4be28&is=66d36ca8&hm=65b57d27db05ee6e2a6fc4456646649e065e420f0c76437a8d2a1dd0ce3ab1c2&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1058&height=544

In fact, by default, I have an entity instance. However, if I pass something into the condition components, I want entity<number> and entity<1|2>. To achieve this, I need to figure out how to prevent never from occurring.

Yes, when I removed the line, all the code turned into never. I should have checked my question beforehand and made sure it was clear. Apologies for the confusion. If only the entry without a component gets never, it should normally be fine because I could assign something else to it.

I edited and added more precision to the question. Sorry about that.

It looks like your RR definition is getting in the way. You're just trying to... prevent unexpected property keys? You could refactor to this version and that looks better to me. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

ho ! I feel like yes ! Thank you so much you’ve made my day, and thanks also for the upcoming explanation

I don't understand at all what's going on! I thought I could make never convert to number with (KA extends AAA ? unknown : number), but it doesn't work. also In fact, removing this line seems to have no effect. I'm a bit lost, I've been working on this for 4 hours and my mind is no longer clear.... so if i understand is not possible to fallback to number ?

If you really need that you can do this approach but this is no longer what your question is asking about. It's just the next thing you hit. Please let me know whether or not I need to worry about this, before I start writing my answer. If so, please [edit] to require that it fall back to number for the element that is missing. If not, let me know and I'll proceed.

I will try to rethink my example. I hadn't realized that it wasn't very clear. I think it was a bad idea to choose numbers, as it introduces a certain condition. I will take an hour to refactor this and return with the issue, as I really don't understand why TypeScript doesn't allow me to infer a parameter in this way.

Yes, that was actually what I was trying to express in my somewhat clumsy English. It's exactly what I meant. I’m sorry for not being clear, as I am very tired. When I ask questions, it's usually because I’ve been doing several hours of trial and error. Thank you so much !!! I think it’s fine even if I no longer understand anything.
not sure how you get this but this work like i want now !

edit done, thank for your time

oki i understand what & (KA extends AAA ? unknown : never) do at the end now :)

i can remove it with this, it seem also work and look more clean for me ```type Param = {
[KA in keyof T & AAA]: {
[KB in keyof T[KA] & BBB]?: TestData<Extract<T[KA][KB], number> extends never ? number : Extract<T[KA][KB], number>>
}
}


No, I was just thinking out loud, your solution hawser my issue

Okay, sounds good. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

It looks like the main problem is that when T is constrained to RR, then as soon as you comment out the line, the inference fails and then T falls back to RR, at which point you get Param<RR> which is equivalent to {[K in AAA]?: {}} and then everything stops working.  I'm not 100% sure why that's happening, but type inference is tricky.
If you remove the constraint then things start to behave:
type Param<T> = {
    [KA in keyof T]: {
        [KB in keyof T[KA]]: (
            TestData<Extract<T[KA][KB], number>>
        )
    }
}

class Test<T> {
    constructor(
        public readonly data: Param<T>
    ) { }
}

new Test(
    {
        [AAA.a1]: {
            [BBB.b1]: {
                avaible: (c) => {
                    //    ^? (parameter) c: never
                }
            },
        },
        [AAA.a2]: {
            [BBB.b2]: {
                components: [5],
                avaible: (c) => {
                    //    ^? (parameter) c: 5
                }
            },
            [BBB.b1]: {
                components: [8],
                avaible: (c) => {
                    //    ^? (parameter) c: 8
                }
            },
        },
    }
);

Now only the missing components has never inferred. If you want this to fall back to number instead (which shouldn't be necessary, you are always allowed to annotate (c: number) => {} if you want), then you can use an additional conditional type:
type OrElse<T, D> = [T] extends [never] ? D : T;

type Param<T> = {
    [KA in keyof T]: {
        [KB in keyof T[KA]]: (
            TestData<OrElse<Extract<T[KA][KB], number>, number>>
        )
    }
}

new Test(
    {
        [AAA.a1]: {
            [BBB.b1]: {
                avaible: (c) => {
                    //    ^? (parameter) c: number
                }
            },
        },
        [AAA.a2]: {
            [BBB.b2]: {
                components: [5],
                avaible: (c) => {
                    //    ^? (parameter) c: 5
                }
            },
            [BBB.b1]: {
                components: [8],
                avaible: (c) => {
                    //    ^? (parameter) c: 8
                }
            },
        },
    }
);

Looks good!

At this point the only issue is that T can have all kinds of keys, not just AAA or BBB:
 new Test({x: {}}); // no error?!

You can add back the constraint in a number of ways, possibly by mapping properties with unexpected keys to never, like:
type Param<T> = {
    [KA in keyof T]: {
        [KB in keyof T[KA]]: (
            TestData<OrElse<Extract<T[KA][KB], number>, number>>
        ) & (KB extends BBB ? unknown : never)
    } & (KA extends AAA ? unknown : never)
}

which leaves the good cases alone but gives you errors on
new Test({ x: {} }); // error!

I'll say the exact way to prevent unexpected key/values is out of scope here, and that the main point is to remove the constraint extends RR and to use a conditional type on Extract<T[KA][KB], number> to cause never to become number.
Playground link to code
